# How do web-based ajax IRC clients overcome the IRC server's connection limit?

Tags: ajax, proxy, irc

Most IRC networks enforce a small limit to the number of connections allowed from each IP address (eg 5 connections per IP).

AJAX clients like [Mibbit](http://mibbit.com/) allow seemingly unlimited clients to connect to a network through their server.

How is this possible given that the IRC server should place a limit on the number of connections allowed from the server hosting the AJAX client (the Mibbit server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Mibbit wiki on IRC Server settings](http://wiki.mibbit.com/index.php/Enable_Mibbit_on_Your_IRC_Server). Essentially, Mibbit doesn't get around the connection limit, the irc server itself allows Mibbit to connect.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean if I wanted to implement IRC over http on my website similar to Mibbit, I need to specifically get permission from the IRC network operator?

Comment: Yes, that's what it sounds like.